# Prove that raising a squared matrix to the power, keep its non linear rows

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

I need to prove  that raising a square matrix to any power, e.g. 3x3, will not change its non linear rows, meaning that in the end of gaussian
elimination, I have the same matrix. Condition: at least one of the diagonal elements is not zero

e.g.

A=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 &3 \\ 
 2& 4 & 6\\ 
0 & 1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}

after gaussian elimination:
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 &3 \\ 
 0& 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
will still have same gaussian elimination result, even if I solve A^33 and then conduct gaussian elimination

Comment: What are the non-linear rows of a matrix?  I don't understand what you are asking at all.  Do you mean squaring a matrix?  Raising a square matrix to some power?  Any power?  Can you give an example of the general phenomenon you are trying to prove?

Comment: I have edited the question, I hope this is more clear

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the statement, it isn't true.  Consider
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&1&0\end{pmatrix}\\
A^2=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: You are right. I should have been more precise. One of the diagnoal elements is not zero. For example, the first matrix I wrote is a good example to what I need to prove

Comment: I still have no idea what you mean.  "One of the diagonal elements is not $0$."  What are you talking about?

Comment: Wikipedia says I mean:main diagonal entries

Comment: The answer to what I'm looking for is something like: because the columns of the multiplied matrix can be seen as linear combination of the rows of the multiplier matrix(i.e. the left one), then the rank of the matrix cannot change (as we have at least one non zero entry in the main diagonal), and we reach the same gaussian elimination at the end